# Make code smaller

Tags: php

Im trying to learn some PHP coding and started to make my own small project.
But my code is pretty big and it will be bigger when i'm done coding this part and i really like to learn how to make this smaller maybe u guys can help me.

Here is what it is al about.

Getting database connection and recieving the needed information.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users, Achievements WHERE USER_ID = 0 AND ACHIEVEMENT_ID = 0";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$conn->close();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach($row AS $key => $value)
   {
    $$key = trim($value);
   }

}} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

I created some variables and started to make a array i will finish this but i think this part can be smaller.

```
$achievement1 = array("Bench press","50 kilo reached.","60 kilo reached.","80 kilo reached.","100 kilo reached.");
$achievement2 = array("Deadlift","50 kilo reached.","60 kilo reached.","80 kilo reached.","100 kilo reached.");
$achievement3 = 'Dipping';
$achievement4 = 'Squats';
$achievement5 = 'Total';
```

And now the biggest part i want to learn more about the part that the values are checked and the echo will be given this is to bigg and 3 more parts will add under it but this can be smaller i guess.

```
if ($ACHIEVEMENT_1 <= 49) {
    echo "Youre weak.";
} else if (($ACHIEVEMENT_1 > 49) && ($ACHIEVEMENT_1 < 60)) {
    echo $achievement1[1]; 
} else if (($ACHIEVEMENT_1 > 59) && ($ACHIEVEMENT_1 < 80)) {
    echo $achievement1[2]; 
} else if (($ACHIEVEMENT_1 > 79) && ($ACHIEVEMENT_1 < 100)) {
    echo $achievement1[3];
} else if ($ACHIEVEMENT_1 > 99) {
    echo $achievement1[4];
} 
if ($ACHIEVEMENT_2 <= 49) {
    echo "Youre weak.";
} else if (($ACHIEVEMENT_2 > 49) && ($ACHIEVEMENT_2 < 60)) {
    echo $achievement2[1]; 
} else if (($ACHIEVEMENT_2 > 59) && ($ACHIEVEMENT_2 < 80)) {
    echo $achievement2[2]; 
} else if (($ACHIEVEMENT_2 > 79) && ($ACHIEVEMENT_2 < 100)) {
    echo $achievement2[3];
} else if ($ACHIEVEMENT_2 > 99) {
    echo $achievement2[4];
}
```

Hope you guys are enable to shorter this code with me.

**EDIT i have changed this**

```
<?php
    $achievement = array
    (
    array("Bench press","50 kilo reached.","60 kilo reached.","80 kilo reached.","100 kilo reached."),
    array("Deadlift","50 kilo reached.","60 kilo reached.","80 kilo reached.","100 kilo reached."),
    array("Dipping","50 kilo reached.","60 kilo reached.","80 kilo reached.","100 kilo reachxed."),
    array("Squats","50 kilo reached.","60 kilo reached.","80 kilo reached.","100 kilo reached."),
    array("Total","50 kilo reached.","60 kilo reached.","80 kilo reached.","100 kilo reached."),
    );

for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row++) {
    echo "<p><b>Achievement: ". $achievement[$row][0] ."</b></p>";
    echo "<ul>";
    for ($col = 1; $col < 4; $col++) {
        echo "<li>".$achievement[$row][$col]."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
?>
```

But i need the values added and cannot figure it out yet.

Comment: You can do your IF's with a For imo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is working code and the question should ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jens sorry mate i just want to learn some more coding

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten this snippet:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    /* USER NAME */
    $USERNAME = $row["USER_NAME"];
    /* BENCH PRESS */
    $ACHIEVEMENT_1 = $row["ACHIEVEMENT_1"];
    /* DEAD LIFT */
    $ACHIEVEMENT_2 = $row["ACHIEVEMENT_2"];
    /* DIPPING */
    $ACHIEVEMENT_3 = $row["ACHIEVEMENT_3"];
    /* SQUATS */
    $ACHIEVEMENT_4 = $row["ACHIEVEMENT_4"];
    /* TOTAL */
    $ACHIEVEMENT_5 = $row["ACHIEVEMENT_5"];
}}
```

by writing it this way:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach($row AS $key => $value)
   {
    $$key = trim($value);
   }

}}
```